# Why Mozilla put Object.assign polyfill in an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, polyfills, iife

I have a question.

In the Polyfill section of [MDN page for Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) function.

The technical writers in Mozilla put a polyfill of `Object.assign` in an anonymous function:

```
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  (function () {
    Object.assign = function (target) {
      ...
    };
  })(); // <-- anonymous function call
}
```

What is the different if we just put `Object.assign = function (target) {` directly inside the `if` statement without the anonymous function here?

Why would they do that?

Comment: MDN is like an [open wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/About), [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign$compare?to=976783&from=975633) is the diff for that change, since the anonymous function does nothing else besides the assignation I think you can get rid of it safely

Comment: I'm just curious about why would they do it :D I want to know if is it a new habit of JS developers who just wanted to put everything in an anonymous function just to make it more self-contained or not :D

Comment: Well that was the pattern that developers used to do to avoid polluting the global execution context however now we can isolate code in their own files and just require them whenever we want, bundlers do most of the work now

Comment: This should be tagged with IIFE

Answer (score 0):

> The technical writers in Mozilla

Not all editors of MDN are technical writers, it's an open wiki.

> Why would they put Object.assign polyfill in an anonymous function?

There's absolutely no reason here. It might have been useful to store static values, such as a reference to `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` in there, but that was not done so the IIFE was superfluous. [I've removed it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign$compare?locale=en-US&to=1064770&from=1062604).